# Add own Identity Provider to Azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I want to build a webapp where users can log into to consume some services, view data and so on. The user can set up a new account and then log into with this account, just like the normal way you log in to many different web sites.

As I am already using Azure, I came across Azure AD B2C which seems to be perfect for my needs. I have seen that you can also include some other identity providers like facebook or google.
Is it possible to integrate a completely own identity provider? I'm already using a different user validation system for another application in form of a WCF service which validates user credentials against a sql database.

Is it possible to forward the login data, the user inputs into the webapp, from Azure AD B2C to my wcf service to validate the credentials against the existing user db?

Comment: Do you mean you are wanting to use the Azure AD B2C service over an existing identity store rather than the default directory?

Comment: I want to use both. I have already existing (special) users in a (different) sql db which I can access via a wcf service, which I do not want to store in azure and I do not want to mix with the users stored in azure. But when I'm typing the credentials into the azure login UI in the webapp, I additionally want to check against the existing users not stored in azure using the wcf service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can do this but this feature is in preview 
Azure AD B2C => Identity providers => Add => Select Identity provider type  as **Open Connect (Preview)**
Setup Identity provider following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-oidc-idp)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to forward the login data, the user inputs into the webapp, from Azure AD B2C to my wcf service to validate the credentials against the existing user db?

No, you cannot pass along the user input login data.  You can federate with IDPs (identity providers) where the login occurs on the IDP.

As stated in Arunraja’s answer, B2C has support to plug-in a OpenID Connect IDP.